# USB headset not detecting on stock 20.10 install

Tags: sound, 20.10

I previously had 18.04 and sound was working.  If I plugged in a USB-C headset I could hit the volume controls and it would display an overlay on the screen showing me the volume going up and down.

Now I recently installed 20.10 from scratch (mainly because 18.04 refused to upgrade for many reasons) and I just noticed that when I try to play sound I hear it from the speakers, even when the USB headset is plugged in.  Additionally, I cannot turn the volume up or down.

If I plug in a headset to the 2.5mm headset plug, sound no longer comes out of the speakers, but it also doesn't come out of the headset.

When I go to Settings > Sound I am able to move the "System Volume" slider, but it does not affect the volume.  Under "Output Device" there are no output devices shown as available.

How can I get sound working properly so I can control the volume through my Fn+F1/2/3 keys as well as working via the USB-C headset?

update: In a comment to another answer I found a suggestion to run `pulseaudio -vvv`.  But what I discovered is that running pulseaudio at all from the command line fixes the issue.  But this requires me to run it manually, ties up a terminal, and stops working if pulseaudio is killed.  So I suspect that something should be starting/retaining pulseaudio and isn't.